# Accessing the the coordinates in a QPushbutton clicked slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QPushButton with an image that has two areas that I want to handle differently when clicked.  Due to the positioning on the image, I cannot really use separate buttons for the two images.

What I'd like to do is, in the slot where I am handling the click, have it check the coordinates of the click to determine which area was clicked.

Is there a way to access this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what first comes to mind. It should work, although there may be a simpler way:

- Create your own class that derives from `QPushButton`.
- Override the necessary mouse events (`mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`) and, before calling the base class implementation, set a property in your object using `setProperty` with the position of the mouse click. (The position is available from the event parameter.)
- In the slot handling the event, use `sender()` to get the button, and read the property using `property()`.

If you don't need to treat your object as the base class (`QPushButton*`) you could just create a new signal that includes the mouse event and attach that to your slot. Then you wouldn't need the property at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current mouse position using QCursor::pos() which returns the position of the cursor (hot spot) in global screen coordinates.

Now screen coordinates are not easy to use, and probably not what you want.  Luckily there is a way to transform screen coordinates to coordinates relative to a widget.

```
QPoint _Position = _Button->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
```

This should tell you where on the button the mouse was when the user clicked.  And you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Liz's simple mechanism, here's what I did; this is in a slot method that is called on pressed() but generalizes to other situations.  Note that using pushButton->geometry() gives you coordinates that are already in global space so you don't need to mapFromGlobal.

```
void MainWindow::handlePlanButtonPress()
{
    int clickX = QCursor::pos().x();
    int middle = m_buttonPlan->geometry().center().x();

    if ( clickX < middle ) {
        // left half of button was pressed
        m_buttonPlan->setStyleSheet(sStyleLargeBlueLeft);
    } else {
        // right half of button was pressed
        m_buttonPlan->setStyleSheet(sStyleLargeBlueRight);
    }
}
```